# Update Specific Key Value in Complex `wp_options` object

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-options, options

This should b really easy but I can't find reference - easy points for someone!

I have an option in my `wp_options` table, and need to set it via `update_option()`.  I just can't find the correct syntax for doing something similar to the following where I update the key `object_key` in the option `my_plugin_settings` where this is an option in my `wp_options` table:

`update_option('my_plugin_settings[object_key]','new value');`

How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being dense, you need to grab the object, overwrite the key you want to set and then save the updated object as the new option:

```
$my_plugin_settings = get_option('my_plugin_settings');
$my_plugin_settings->object_key = 'new_value';
update_option('my_plugin_settings', $my_plugin_settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't update a key, you get the entire option group as an array, then update the key you want, like normal array edit, then update the entire option group.

```
$option_group = get_option('group_name');

$option_group['option_to_update'] = 'new value';

update_option( 'group_name', $option_group );
```